# shell_exec() is acting strange

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a C program that I've written that turns IP addresses into countries by looking up a big CSV database. I'm trying to call it via `shell_exec` but something is going wrong.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors','1');

 set_time_limit(0);

 $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $country = shell_exec("/var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country $ipaddress");
?>
```

I've checked:

- PHP isn't running in safe mode (`safe_mode = Off`);
- The command executes fine when I leave the IP address off and returns (as expected) `Usage: ip2country IPAddress` - so I assume it ain't a permissions thing;
- I've set `set_time_limit` to `0` so it's not a timing out thing as far as I can tell.

What am I doing wrong?

*[This might be more of a Linux thing and not a PHP thing after all.]*

Output from test commands:

```
[root@rhel ip2country]# /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country 4.2.2.2
United States

[root@rhel ip2country]# sudo -u apache /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country 4.2.2.2
United States

[user@rhel ip2country]$ sudo -u apache /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country 4.2.2.2
// No output whatsoever

[user@rhel ip2country]$ sudo -u apache /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country
Usage: /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country IPAddress
```

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9429 Jun  1 10:55 /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country

Comment: Try `echo shell_exec("/var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country $ipaddress 2>&1");` to see error messages printed by your program to stderr.

Comment: Please don't take this as a sarcastic remark. I mean it sincerely. If you were able to write that script in `C`, you are probably capable of porting it to `PHP`. That might be your better choice

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference but you should probably run the IP address through `escapeshellarg`

Comment: @TecBrat: Fair point but I'm concerned about load/processing speed (the IP lookup tables are pretty large).

Comment: Putting the IP tables into a database (MySQL, PostgreSQL...) might allow you to process them in an acceptable amount of time.

Comment: Sounds like I'll have to give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `whoami` instead of your program and then, when you know, what user is used to ecevute it, check whether he has proper permissions.

If you say, that without IP it works OK, then, I guess, you use some database or file to look up IPs. Maybe this user does not have access to that database or file.

Comment: try from command line: sudo /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country 8.8.8.8 -u  apache

Comment: Weird.

'sudo -u apache /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country 4.2.2.2' returns nothing but 'sudo -u apache /var/www/html/ip2country/ip2country' returns the usage statement.

Comment: Then it's permissions. Where do you get your data from?

Comment: I get data from a CSV file stored in the same directory. When I do shell_exec("ls -l /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv") I get: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12546388 Jun 1 10:55 /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv

Comment: sudo -u apache cat /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv

Comment: And move those file out of your www root, or else whole world will be able to download them

Comment: Just did 'chmod 777 /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv' and 'chown apache:apache /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv' and it's still not working, so I don't think it's a permissions thing.

Comment: sudo -u apache cat /var/www/html/ip2country/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv returns the file output as expected.